# X509Certficate2 issue when using iPhone Apple Push Notification Provider (apns-sharp)

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate2, apns-sharp

using APNS-Sharp in a .Net web service on a Rackspace cloud site.

I'm getting hung up with no response at all when instantiating a new X509. Using apns-sharp it's this line:

```
public ApplePushChannelSettings(bool production, byte[] certificateData, string certificateFilePwd)
: this(production, new X509Certificate2(certificateData, certificateFilePwd,
X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)) { }
g.log("APNSPush clientCertificate success - NEVER GETS HERE");
```

I've also tried a different approach using this line, but same hanging response...

```
clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
g.log("APNSPush clientCertificate success - NEVER GETS HERE");
```

Oddly there aren't any errors being caught so I'm not sure what's going on. I had suspected it was a key store access issue trying to get to the private key of the cert(p12) I'm using but I just don't know.

Comment: turns out that Rackspace just informed me that this is due to limitations on access to the key store in the cloud site environment and I have to upgrade to a cloud server for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

turns out that Rackspace just informed me that this is due to limitations on access to the key store in the cloud site environment and I have to upgrade to a cloud server for this functionality